# Swap encoding iteration count

Tags: fastest-code

## Introduction

In [this challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/22202#22202), I asked you to implement swap encoding.

Swap encoding is an encoding method where you iterate through the string, reversing substrings between identical characters. The basic algorithm is:

For each character in the string:

Check: Does the string contain the character again, after the instance you found?

If so, then modify the string by reversing the section between the character and the next instance, inclusive.

Otherwise do nothing.

## Example

Start with the string 'eat potatoes'.

e is found again, so reverse that section: `eotatop taes`
o is found again, so reverse that section (doing nothing as it is palindromic)
t is found again, so reverse that section (doing nothing as it is palindromic)
a is found again, so reverse that section: `eotat potaes`
t is found again, so reverse that section: `eotatop taes`
None of 'op taes' are found again, so `eotatop taes` is our final string!

Anyway, in [this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123489/discussing-swap-function), @okie and I discussed what would happen if you repeatedly ran the swap algorithm on something until it returned to the original string. We managed to prove that it will always return.

Okay, that's a lot of preamble. Here's your challenge:

Write a program or function that takes a string as input, and returns the number of times it has to be swapped before it will return to itself.

## Scoring

Answers will be timed on their combined score on all the scored testcases, so please append a snippet to your program that runs all the testcases one after another.

I will time all answers on all on my computer (2018 Macbook Air), although please link to a downloadable interpreter/compiler for less mainstream languages.

[Here](https://tio.run/##ZZBdboMwEITfOcX2zY6JiSn5qVLO0AMgpCBik42QjWxCLFU5OwXSIpS@2ZpvZnf2WnSFKy027Vqbs@x7ddNli0aDuxcN8fQ7AEBIYXMcHvcL1pIgfILntdRVe5l0ADUQnrsay0FmgnLUZ@m/FPEZ5nRCUBEFb2kKa/FrAvAL2yZEyjLO@ZwTKoYspjm3spPWSUL51aA@nYDNricyxT2eYxgbNx0/VrY3q8Efg0fQFXaqMbVqrCmlc7ywVZfFOQ2nRUQQRaXRztSS16b6R73ISIO/c4ytXmmIVgt6FZF5OoaeMUqDZZinfd/H79vksPvYi3grkljsD3HyAw) is my reference implementation.

## Testcases

## Simple testcases (Just to check it works):

```
1231 => 2
1234512345 => 6
123142523
Sandbox for Proposed Challenges => 1090
Collatz, Sort, Repeat => 51
Rob the King: Hexagonal Mazes => 144
Decompress a Sparse Matrix => 8610
14126453467324231 => 1412
12435114151241 - 288
Closest Binary Fraction => 242
Quote a rational number => 282
Solve the Alien Probe puzzle => 5598
```

## Scored testcases (The ones I'm timing you on)

```
124351141512412435325 => 244129
Write a fast-growing assembly function => 1395376
And I'm now heading to the elevator => 207478
I'm in the now infamous elevator => 348112
1549827632458914598012734 => 1025264
i was always mediocre at golfing => 1232480
tho, i like some code challenges => 2759404
I am once again in an elevator => 1606256
A person with mannerism of cat => 867594
```

## IMPORTANT

To make it fair, I have to time all programs under the same load on my computer. So if one person requests a retime, I have to retime them all. This means your time may fluctate.

Comment: My elevator journey shall forever be known now

Comment: @Lyxal I can even link to the transcript if you really want me to.

Comment: You don't have to - the references are enough

Comment: It would be better to have your first link point to the main site rather than the sandbox.

Comment: I guess you could submit the sequence of maximum cycle length for a given string size on OEIS: `1,1,1,2,3,4,6,12,38,117,234,650,...`

Comment: On my MacBook the first run is typically bit slower?! CPU cache warm-up? CPU throttling? Please consider repeating in a loop and dividing by the count for better accuracy. For zsh (recent MacOS) try: `time (repeat 10 ./foo)`, for bash (old MacOS) try: `time (for i in {1..10}; do ./foo; done)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## C, 1.972 seconds

In 2021 we don't have faster CPUs, we just have more cores. Let's use them! Naive implementation using POSIX threads to parallelize. A simple but fast hash is used to save some string compares.

Update: unrolled loop for short distances to shave off 9% percent.

Update 2: flag unique characters to prevent unnecessary searching for duplicate character (saves additional 12%, now saved 19% over original code).

```c
// To compile:
//    $ gcc -Wall -O3 JasonSmith.c -lpthread -o JasonSmith
//
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define UNIQUE_MASK  (0x80)

/**
 * Test Vectors with expected answers.
 */
typedef struct {
   const char *text;
   int         expected;
} test_vector_t;
 
test_vector_t test_vectors[] = {
   {  "124351141512412435325",                  244129   },
   {  "Write a fast-growing assembly function", 1395376  },
   {  "And I'm now heading to the elevator",    207478   },
   {  "I'm in the now infamous elevator",       348112   },
   {  "1549827632458914598012734",              1025264  },
   {  "i was always mediocre at golfing",       1232480  },
   {  "tho, i like some code challenges",       2759404  },
   {  "I am once again in an elevator",         1606256  },
   {  "A person with mannerism of cat",         867594   },
};
int nr_test_vectors = sizeof(test_vectors)/sizeof(test_vectors[0]);

/**
 * Worker thread
 * @param test vector to process
 */
void process(test_vector_t *test_vector) {
   
   // swap encoding is destructive, so first make copy
   // of challenge text in separate buffer
   char text[strlen(test_vector->text) + 1 + 5];
   memset(text, 0, sizeof(text));
   strcpy(text, test_vector->text);

   // flag unique characters by setting high bit
   for (char *p = text; *p; p++) {
      assert((*p & UNIQUE_MASK) == 0);  // assume no "weird" UTF-8 chars
      int is_unique = 1;
      for (char *q = text; *q; q++) {
          if (p == q) continue;
          if (*p == *q) {
            is_unique = 0;
            break;
          }
      }
      if (is_unique) *p |= UNIQUE_MASK;
   }

   // flagged text no longer matches original text, so we must
   // save flagged text as the new "original" for comparison later.
   char orig[strlen(text) + 1];
   strcpy(orig, text);

   // calculcate hash of original text
   unsigned long original_hash = 0;
   for (char *p = text; *p; p++) {
      original_hash = original_hash*31 + *p;
   }

   // repeatedly swap encode until original text is back
   unsigned long hash;
   unsigned int count = 0;
   do {
      hash = 0;
      for (char *p = text; *p; p++) {
         hash = hash*31 + *p;
         
         // no need to search for duplicate of unique character
         if ((*p & UNIQUE_MASK) != 0) continue;
         
         // unrolled loop for short distances
         if (p[0] == p[1]) continue;
         if (p[0] == p[2]) continue;
         if (p[0] == p[3]) {
            char temp = p[1];
            p[1] = p[2];
            p[2] = temp;
            continue;
         }
         if (p[0] == p[4]) {
            char temp = p[1];
            p[1] = p[3];
            p[3] = temp;
            continue;
         }
         if (p[0] == p[5]) {
            char temp = p[1];
            p[1] = p[4];
            p[4] = temp;
            
            temp = p[2];
            p[2] = p[3];
            p[3] = temp;
            continue;
         }
         
         // scan for larger distances
         char *last = p+6;
         while (*last && *last != *p) last++;
         if (*last) {
            char *start = p;
            while (++start < --last) {
               char temp = *start;
               *start = *last;
               *last = temp;
            }
         }
      }
      count++;
   } while (hash != original_hash || strcmp(orig, text));

   // show result to user
   printf("%-40s -> %8d (%s)\n", test_vector->text, count, 
      (count == test_vector->expected ? "Ok" : "FAIL"));
}

/**
 * Main
 */
int main() {
   pthread_t threads[nr_test_vectors];
   for (int i = 0; i < nr_test_vectors; i++) {
      pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, (void (*))process, test_vectors+i);
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < nr_test_vectors; i++) {
      pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: We'll see how this goes!

Comment: Nice, much faster! You might want to optimise it a bit more.

Comment: Bit more optimization: unrolled loop for short distances. Considered "borrowing" DelfadOr and kops length reduction rules, but that would be lame ;-)

Comment: Also: flag unique characters to prevent unnecessary searching for duplicate character. Optimizations saved 19% over original code

Comment: Nice! I think this has improved more than the score suggests, because the other two took longer than they did before.. (I retime every program just to be fair, because the load on my computer varies)

Answer (score 3):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 3.809 seconds

Compile with `g++ -O3 -std=c++14`.

As requested by the OP, the testcases were included in the source.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

constexpr int TESTCASES_NUM = 9;
constexpr char *TESTCASES[TESTCASES_NUM] = {"124351141512412435325", "Write a fast-growing assembly function", "And I'm now heading to the elevator", "I'm in the now infamous elevator", "1549827632458914598012734", "i was always mediocre at golfing", "tho, i like some code challenges", "I am once again in an elevator", "A person with mannerism of cat"};

int solve(char *s, int n) {
    int ans = 0;
    int i, j;
    char *p, *q, b;
    char s0[n];
    memcpy(s0, s, n);
    do {
        for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            for(j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
                if(s[i] == s[j]) {
                    for(p = s + i + 1, q = s + j - 1; p < q; ++p, --q) {
                        b = *p;
                        *p = *q;
                        *q = b;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        ++ans;
    } while (memcmp(s0, s, n));
    return ans;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    for(int t = 0; t < TESTCASES_NUM; ++t) {
        char* s = TESTCASES[t];
        int  n = strlen(s);
        
        int count[300];
        memset(count, 0, sizeof(count));
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            ++count[s[i]];
        }
        char z[n];
        int m = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            if(count[s[i]] == 1) {
                if(i > 1 and count[s[i - 1]] == 1 and count[s[i - 2]] == 1) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if(i > 1 and s[i] == s[i - 2] and count[s[i - 1]] == 1) {
                --m;
                continue;
            }
            if(m == 0 and count[s[i]] == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            z[m++] = s[i];
        }
        while(m > 1 and count[z[m - 1]] == 1) {
            --m;
        }
        
        printf("%d\n", solve(z, m));
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVVLb9pAEL77V4yoqhpsV5hHk4gkUlTl0EPbQ1L1QFG12GuzxN413iU0RPz10lkbsB3MoysO3tlv5psn4yWJE3reev2OcS@a@xSupfKZ@Di5NcqilPHwrcyP2FjLDE9wqeifJAXGFTzePzx@vnu4f/j97cdXuIGrQQngTUgKrR1kWAGPEP3acDu9bt91e24fv7JLt9Nv2ND4mTJFgUBApHLCVCzQJyBS0ngcvUAw555igmvkHffhy4cYuFjAhBJfA5UANaFAI/pMlEg1TEMYz8QayXhAYjGXFYzb711ddi4@dTu9/uWV2@tfXbbdzkW3px8ZLIgEEi3Ii4SYYt68FD1UEIooQFKNURNhA4OIPVGQIqbgCUwf5iGKKA@pzBwBEoPgHuqGBD3CH@EVN@4goakUHBZMTSAmnNOUSVQKwCOqsRoYhs69FNEzNfMkSzsrB2/CqwF49IVwiTluD3YCZsM0v@VKiQ2tmQ3jkky2h3yU32Mae8mLKds2oHXezKW@2DDoE4jUZBkHBn0NfACWxZolwBY0RRADC9wBTLfA6Vtg5mZgyiHD3rgBOZyO6iBbmwnalGgzs2vDbHOdgqNpEqSZaRoM0nFmhwzpM0bNVjI4@N7STK3ZEYDmHte/r2ql45SSp32FKri4FV@WhVXNFVewmLCIgqkLFSdFoTaVSqmap7q3EL/KOybGfjOz1khDz950QQsvz9v8ZBVFgMqrqjCLlanVGVXlZGobLdCNVsy5GhWhaWPAdW1UijNgymbxVgF5Ys7VsNtul5QxMkmVmT3ZoONjSyqCXNAsWdq6fbIZLSvn0U1WIlpV4oHlbgi23sXFJP0XH9s4mxPqtnYPtD2DW3CxWj7sFHQnb5T2HjpHrGVxCK4Yn9Pzm2zPj2IQc8KDztX54DjxPnW9U3suxNpqu0qXU7XrqM6xuhzGlqVXjjZVV/dslpC5WgRUOxJnJcbVflsnuEhVYDbe@7/0psr/r5c2xNvWXeFgrte1O9A4bwEaZ2w/49TqMw7uPePU0jNObTzj@Lozju@6v14QkVCune/dfw)

The naive implementation, with a couple of preprocessing optimizations.

Say that a character is *unique* if it occurs exactly once in the input string.

- If there are more than 2 consecutive unique characters, we can remove some of them until there are exactly 2 consecutive ones.
- We can remove every prefix or suffix consisting entirely of unique characters.
- We can make substitutions `aba -> a` whenever `b` is unique (thanks to [kops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101474/kops) for the suggestion!).

Comment: Nice! Will time!

Comment: @Ausername I just noticed that you need a script to run all the testcases one after the other, I will add it soon.

Comment: Yeah, I was about to ask... Just add another comment so it notifies me when you're done.

Comment: @Ausername I actually changed the program so that it can take more than one input, each one on a separate line.

Comment: I get `error: use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr'` when I try to compile it. Edit: I didn't have the `-static`, nvm.

Comment: "If there is a unique character without any unique neighbors, we can delete it from the string." <- This is false in general. Consider `abcab` (period 2) vs `abab` (period 1). I believe your second observation is correct, though.

Comment: On the other hand, another (admittedly small) optimization you can do is reduce repeated letters like `aa`->`a`.

Comment: @kops Well that's awkward ^^. Thanks for the second comment, I will probably implement that later.

Comment: Another optimization: you can delete the longest prefix of unique characters completely. And another small one: `aba` -> `a` is valid whenever `b` is unique. This happens at least a couple times in `*ele*vator`.

Comment: For the 7th test case, removing one of the doubled letters (`ll` in `challenges`) results in half as many iterations as the reference implementation. I'm unsure why. Both programs give the same result for, say, the 2nd test case (which has `ss` in `assembly`).

Comment: @Dingus Yes, sorry. It should be fixed now (and I also added the other optimizations suggested by kops above).

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 5.383 seconds

```c
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned int f(char* str)
{
    unsigned int count = 0;

    char original[strlen(str) + 1];
    strcpy(original, str);

    do {
        for (char* current = str; *current; ++current)
        {
            for (
                    char* last = index(current + 1, *current),
                    *start = current;
                    last > start;
                )
            {
                char temp = *start;
                *start++ = *last;
                *last-- = temp;
            }
        }
        ++count;
    } while (strcmp(original, str));

    return count;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
#ifdef SIMPLE
    char* tests[] = {"1231", "1234512345", "123142523", "Sandbox for Proposed Challenges", "Collatz, Sort, Repeat", "Rob the King: Hexagonal Mazes", "Decompress a Sparse Matrix", "14126453467324231", "12435114151241", "Closest Binary Fraction", "Quote a rational number", "Solve the Alien Probe puzzle"};
    int expected[] = {2, 6, 4, 1090, 51, 144, 8610, 1412, 288, 242, 282, 5598};
#else
    char* tests[] = {"124351141512412435325", "Write a fast-growing assembly function", "And I'm now heading to the elevator", "I'm in the now infamous elevator", "1549827632458914598012734", "i was always mediocre at golfing", "tho, i like some code challenges", "I am once again in an elevator", "A person with mannerism of cat"};
    int expected[] = {244129, 1395376, 207478, 348112, 1025264, 1232480, 2759404, 1606256, 867594};
#endif

    char* checker[]   = {"\xE2\x9C\x95", "\xE2\x9C\x93"};
    for (int index = 0; index < sizeof(expected)/sizeof(*expected); ++index) {
        char* t = tests[index];
        char buff[strlen(t) + 1];
        strcpy(buff, t);
        int s = f(buff);
        int e = expected[index];
        printf("\"%s\" -> %d %s\n", t, s, checker[e==s]);
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVXbbts4EH3XVwwcFGs78sa6@bJpAmTTFht0g@02D/vQ5IGWKJkoRQqkFDsO/OubztCyY@ciwDI5c@bCOaNhOkglU8XTSR8usgwGn@Dm6vrb358h1WUlJDeQS1ZArcE0CqwoK8mh5rZOmeXQP3k6EiqVTcbho62NUIX9fX7uvRS@lGVCvxJJMSOZ1ygrCsUzEKqGvJvOmekDuul5jx7gc6BPdYPvMxieek5JaNBGFEIx@QOtJFddMoZjCO5OHQa3afXQ3aJ857y1zzRsotCTawNt/LQxhrtICD6Ffrs/hePjdtnbmT072Dk5kGyfjWfJLLkVKuPL7jYMJuvvgvT8N837tmaGTLe5vIly7s/BYV8jegeSR@@tFJHtssIw/Xd8bOTHxwShaG8gSDwYIIBcHerX3usV1pRo3QDXsJhjHwKxmJbVC9q2vBleN0ZBa7f2PGqOkgnVpQUzRepv6t2nzT310pHIM5637e49E0LNbX/cYbaPnSCMgo4P9B8n7tXugjhMwog2N0xlM710PH8zutIWW/NyziR2XsEtQS61lKxe@XCjTe3Dd15xVpPiu55BPefwFT@RP@AvvmSFxqPBNVttLD9x@gwNtxYY3FTM4Dd3zfCTWro84iAcxUkUj8ZRGO9SjaMkQBXmGzvJpcScsAv@xLKZB/hiWFoLrUj1b6Nrjq4NIwlGVk0548adS8t77rK7kIIrOtuMQ9WsVpJ31htuqLZ8WfG05tmmYqEPIx9iH4LhdOhDgm0cxLidjIIhLQMEhJMJvmK3wleSTCfo74hLy9@lYf9MtIlCx8R/Rrj8c2qwwugFFhKYtbycyQfIG7U76YXK4Oq3EpRewJyzjIA41Oh8XPJ7Vmt3aoII5cSEFCpnpW7sASZI4ukkHI@w5slkGsSY/zAIx1FMSgELhmTJBXuwUHIcdKnBDGsotMwxKGHqufZBgBQ/OVhdcmxbnIHpQc9cAStBqxRtC2xjSoqpgzQuoOLGagULUc@x15XiRlg0yiHF9nqfohhLOEUyomkSjZGtcDiOx0hJFE8C4icYYm@PiMMQjzhB3sJxMo2HJBkNR2EyIj5J5GhTmci9PeLSOU9/coPBwJF3u/wc3i6nl/hznO3to22WbkhSqm4MunneLj/inbPiOu9uD9E7aQX9nYSmsEP39kZY20Vu6FAnOcDd6YEeZk2eb2@Jev@O2LsnCOND3XtWUKIWHedO90LBUbEr@MugFV6Gdd7t3HY@2NsODM7hQwa4pBbFyWD9XfX42Zm9a12vvfXT0/8pXcT2afBP9As)

Compile with `-O3`.

Comment: Yes. Will time.

Comment: 48 milliseconds ????!?!?!?!??!?!?!?!?

Comment: Did you define SCORE to run the right tests?

Comment: Oops no. Will do.

Comment: Changed it to run score tests by default

Comment: Did you compile it with `-O3`?

Comment: Yes - Idk why it's being slower than you thought.

Comment: Hmmn, 6.665 seconds this time. What is happening?

Comment: Are you running other stuff on your computer?

Comment: Yes, I think that might be why.

Comment: Just ran&timed both now and got 6.665 for you and 3.732 for the other one. I think I'm just going to recompile and run all of them every time there's a new answer.

Comment: That's fair, it gives a good comparison testing them all under the same load.

Comment: It does mean everyones' results are going to change slightly every time there's a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 9.659 seconds

Port of [@Delfad0r's C++ answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225055/110802) in Rust.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVVNb@IwEL3zK6YcsolaIsLH9oOlUlX1sGeq3QNCyDVOYurYUeyASstfX3YcCKQJq66FIifzZua9GY/Jcm12O22I4RSenybPjw@Tp8kdOFNHm2wGY9y1AFc76A36wyAYBEPcFS/93rB9tTf@zrhhQCAk2nSiTK25jIBozZIX8QZhLqnhSpboB7mAn98SkGoNMSMLCzYKTMyACbYiRmUl1MK4LEwWzWVIEpXrBi4YDm5vetff@73B8OY2GAxvb7pB77o/KAEc1kQDEWvypiFhC65ohowNREqESKDEmVhdAQfBXxlolTCgaoGPmAjBZMT0kRiQBJSkGCMiyBB/RDZoPUDKMq0krLmJISFSsoxrdAyBEoOo2ajVCiVmEivmJrkBfQe/GP2BCbN7Dzr3wPs9eC@iCWbAQojU2Jfu6PhRZTzikoi5/a59KpRkrnewK5Ue/O0KVYbqkGzX97WPklyvYrWLh0XMCWp3lx4GdDlcQnCEez6Wa@F@OMsP0FOORwRzTpezehy70L73Xc78jK2wFEde5dq2mjsr8HIMwQmJpLRNVFH6Di8ZI6@jg9/@iZ6tbVHRBJty1GZVO4ZpQ4lmVv3xpFdIW9XV6qP00sW3H7Tr@VThMaCmKsK6yaLuRXmwn1WL7RdVuTSIWDF6Me2OoN/tzkafOuLQ2LJydK2GhecUjXh0c803bFary7aZbVNmquUouy6b/d6nKZp5SoTVDs60FOEc7tHkOCc/6EDQ8K0Bev8RfK9ZGi5zNmpYt61/v1VpnU7lIe@XVM/KPE7B3E7Bxk9Vag/UieBXhDY@13OWpOYN/aocavm7Z/Kfr8LnFEgp17FrA3qjM2O0jrlgJxmOwMt5L8Xuzg3@nqG1NipUFqCumgmcqNosfqaRZlwaIS/c9vu2fXW46jbegfIW53W3@0NDQSK96zyq1HTwEmVi3Mc3YdQ4JAZ3hmQRMx2a5mOJf1Yr9hc)

```rust
static TESTCASES: &[&str] = &[
    "124351141512412435325",
    "Write a fast-growing assembly function",
    "And I'm now heading to the elevator",
    "I'm in the now infamous elevator",
    "1549827632458914598012734",
    "i was always mediocre at golfing",
    "tho, i like some code challenges",
    "I am once again in an elevator",
    "A person with mannerism of cat",
];

fn solve(mut s: Vec<char>) -> i32 {
    let mut ans = 0;
    let original_s = s.clone();
    loop {
        for i in 0..s.len() {
            if let Some(j) = (i + 1..s.len()).find(|&j| s[i] == s[j]) {
                s[i + 1..j].reverse();
            }
        }
        ans += 1;
        if s == original_s { break; }
    }
    ans
}

fn main() {
    for &testcase in TESTCASES {
        let s: Vec<char> = testcase.chars().collect();
        let n = s.len();

        let mut count = vec![0; 300];
        for &ch in &s {
            count[ch as usize] += 1;
        }

        let mut z = vec![];
        for i in 0..n {
            if count[s[i] as usize] == 1 {
                if i > 1 && count[s[i - 1] as usize] == 1 && count[s[i - 2] as usize] == 1 {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if i > 1 && s[i] == s[i - 2] && count[s[i - 1] as usize] == 1 {
                if let Some(_) = z.pop() { continue; }
            }
            if z.is_empty() && count[s[i] as usize] == 0 {
                continue;
            }
            z.push(s[i]);
        }
        while let Some(&last) = z.last() {
            if count[last as usize] == 1 { z.pop(); }
            else { break; }
        }
        println!("{}", solve(z));
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of porting one of the other answers into Rust to improve my Rust skills. Nice work. Any idea why it's so much slower? Is there a way to do this without cloning the string? I can't see how that could be the main issue but I also can't see anything else obvious. But I am very much a beginner in Rust.